# Dask map_partitions results in duplicates when reducing and gives wrong results compared to pure pandas

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, dask

When I use dask to groupby using map_partitions, I obtain duplicated data and wrong results compared to simple pandas groupby. But when I use n_partitons=1, I get the correct results. 
Why does this happen? and how can I use multiple partitions and still get the correct results?

my code is

```
measurements = measurements.repartition(n_partitions=38)
measurements.map_partitions(lambda df : df.groupby(["id",df.time.dt.to_period("M"), 
"country","job"]).source.nunique()).compute().reset_index()
```

In pandas, I do

```
measurements.groupby(["id",measurements.time.dt.to_period("M"), 
    "country","job"]).source.nunique().reset_index()
```

PS: I'm using a local cluster on a single machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call map_partitions, you say you want to perform that action on each partition. Given that each unique grouping value can occur in multiple partitions, you will get an entry for each group, for each partition in which it is found.

What if there were a way to do groupby across partitions and have the results smartly merged for you automatically? Fortunately, this is exactly what dask does, and you did not need to use map_partitions at all.

```
measurements.groupby(...).field.nunique().compute()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But does dask support groupby multiple columns? last time I checked, it sais it is not supported.

Comment: Yes, it does. I didn't know they added this functionality. Thanks for the answer @mdurant

Comment: Edit: NotImplementedError: groupby-apply with a multiple Series is currently not supported

Comment: I'm talking about this functionality